# Launch app Iphone portrait, and Ipad landscape

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

**I have this code, i need detect is ipad launch app landscape or iphone in portrait mode only**

```
    NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;

    if([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])
    {
        NSLog(@"This is iPhone");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"This is iPad");
    }
```

Comment: What about the iPod touch? You should use `if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)`

Answer (score -1):

This works!!!  for IOS 6

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)

        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    else
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
```